# Pyspark: Replace value of a column with a value in the dictionary

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe `df` with 3 columns:

```
+---+---------+---------+
| Id| Column_1| Column_2|
+---+---------+---------+
| 11|c1_value1|c2_value1|
| 22|c1_value2|c2_value2|
```

And the list of dictionaries - **data_list**:

```
[
{'id': '11', 'key_1': 123, 'key_2': 456}
{'id': '22', 'key_1': 789, 'key_2': 123}
]
```

I want to replace the value in the **Column_1** column with the value of **key_1** in the dictionary when the **Id** in the dataframe and **id** in the dictionary matches.

So far I have tried this code.

UDF to get the value of the key:

```
def return_col(id):
    for item in data_list:
        if item['id'] == id:
            return item['key_1']

return_col_UDF = udf(lambda z: return_lat(z))
```

call UDF on dataframe:

```
df.select(col('Id'), \
    return_col_udf(col('Id')).alias('Updated_Column')) \
    .show()
```

But it replaced the values of 1 column only. What can I do to change the values of 2 columns: Column_1 & Column_2?

Thank you beforehand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is `udf` needed as you have **`dictionary`**, So convert `dict` to dataframe then join with the existing dataframe.

**`Example:`**

```
#load dict_list as dataframe
df1=spark.createDataFrame([{'id': '11', 'key_1': 123, 'key_2': 456},{'id': '22', 'key_1': 789, 'key_2': 123}])
df1.show()
#+---+-----+-----+
#| id|key_1|key_2|
#+---+-----+-----+
#| 11|  123|  456|
#| 22|  789|  123|
#+---+-----+-----+


df.show()
#+---+--------+--------+
#| Id|column_1|column_2|
#+---+--------+--------+
#| 11|      c1|      c2|
#| 22|      c1|      c2|
#+---+--------+--------+

df.join(df1,['id']).\
withColumn("column_1",col("key_1")).\
withColumn("column_2",col("key_2")).\
drop(*['key_1','key_2']).\
show()
#+---+--------+--------+
#| Id|column_1|column_2|
#+---+--------+--------+
#| 22|     789|     123|
#| 11|     123|     456|
#+---+--------+--------+
```

Comment: got it, let me try!

Comment: **data_list** actually contains dictionaries that have 6 keys (not 3). 

Before converting the list to dataframe, I defined the column names: 

`list_columns = ['id', 'key_1', .... ]`
and created a dataframe: 
`df_list = session.createDataFrame(data = data_list, schema = list_columns)`

in this df_list, id column is showing values of 4th column, and last column is showing values of id column. I can't understand why column names are correct but values are mixed up (wrong order)

Comment: update the question with sample data, will take a look into the issue!